# Ubuntu connects to outside internet, but not to local machines on the network

Tags: networking

Used Ubuntu as a virtual machine on OpenSuSe, liked it, and decided to upgrade.

Now I find while I can connect my 16.04 machine to the internet, I cannot even ping other local computers, or my network printer, much less connect to them. I cannot even connect to the Windows virtual machine I have running under Ubuntu.

Prior to installing, on my hard drive I installed Ubuntu on a USB Stick, where I had the System connect to my Network printer successfully.

Is there a setup switch or option I chose or set wrong? How can I connect to my local network?

Comment: How is the guest network configured? NAT oder bridge?

Comment: What's the IP address of your router, and what's the IP address of your computer? Did you manually set your gateway, address, and mask yourself, or use DHCP?

Comment: My apologies. Further investigation indicates I was connected to my own local network.  The network printer, needed to be powered off and back on because it apparently needed a reset.  

Where as, I could not get from my Ubuntu host to my virtual machine and back because neither had sshd started. Feel silly, but I'm glad things are working. 

While OpenSuSE had/has many good points and features, I am very glad I switched over to Ubuntu.